# How to know if binding has no target in case an object doesn't have that property

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have some classes. Some of them has Color Property, but one does not. I'm using same ListBox User Control for them. I want to hide ColorPicker for those classes that have no such property. I know, I can do a workaround and hide it if DataContext is of certain type, but I want to know if there is a way to check if the binding target isn't just null at a moment, but doesn't exist at all.

I used the proposed converter (returning true/false) with no result, but @mm8 proposal to set FallbackValue to false worked well.

Comment: You could specify a FallbackValue for a specific binding that the target property will be set the when the source property is not found: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Exactly thank you @mm8, you could make an answer, I'll mark it

Comment: Good. It's a weird solution now. A working thing on a not working one, but I'll figure how to do it nicer later and update my question with solution code if I'll like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could specify a `FallbackValue` for a specific binding that the target property will be set the when the source property is not found: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use a ValueConverter for the binding, and in the Convert method, check for `UnsetValue`:

```
<FrameworkElement Property="{Binding SomeProperty, Converter={StaticResource BindingExists}/>
```

and

```
public class BindingExists : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
        {
            // perhaps do something
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }
        else if (value == null)
        {
            // perhaps do something else
        }

        return value
    }

    // ...
```

You can then use `DataTriggers` to display different templates or whatever, in case of null vs. non-existent value.

Comment: It seems that if it fires

`System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Color' property not found on 'object' ''Player' (HashCode=39450669)'. BindingExpression:Path=Color; DataItem='Player' (HashCode=39450669); target element is 'ListBoxItem' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')`
The trigger is not even applying.